# probability theory proof of inequality

Tags: probability-theory

proof

$Var(X + Y) ≥ 1/2 Var(X) − Var(Y)$

if $X$ and $Y$ are random variable with finite second moment.

I believe it has something to do with Markov inequality or Chebyshev inequality, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Hint: For given $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$, how would you minimize the quantity on the left hand side? You'd want to have $Corr(X,Y)=-1$, right? Then $Y = -a X$ for some $a>0$. Then the calculations are easy.